# How I can make nice looking matrix of buttons with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, buttongroup

I have something like that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 6</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 9</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to have a 3x3 matrix of buttons. One more thing, left and right side must look like this example (straight lines):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can make it? Maybe I need to add some Bootstrap class or edit the CSS file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## One group of buttons + few pseudo-classes

1. Use only one block with the `.btn-group` class.
2. Apply a set of CSS properties by using of pseudo-classes:

- [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)
- [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)
- [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [:nth-last-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

3. The `clear: left;` property forces the button to start a new row of the matrix. It's because the `.btn` class has the `float: left;` property.
4. Set up `border-radius` and `margin` properties in a similar way as the `btn-group` class is described in the [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) file.

### Three column button matrix with Bootstrap 3

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/bGWWMRz

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css";

/* Arrange buttons */
.btn-matrix>.btn {
  width: 33%; /* force buttons to have the same width regardless of content */
}
.btn-matrix>.btn:nth-child(3n + 4) {
  clear: left; /* force the button to start a new row of the matrix
                  (because .btn adds the `float: left;` property) */
  margin-left: 0; /* because .btn-group adds `margin-left: -1px;` to all buttons */
}
.btn-matrix>.btn:nth-child(n + 4) {
  margin-top: -1px; /* superimpose borders of the buttons from adjacent rows */
}

/* Fix border radius */
.btn-matrix>.btn:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn-matrix>.btn:nth-child(3) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix>.btn:nth-last-child(3) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix>.btn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

/* Decorations */
.btn-matrix {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-matrix">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 6</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 7</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 8</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 9</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 10</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 11</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 12</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 13</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 14</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 15</button>
</div>
```

##### X×Y matrix with Bootstrap 3

The code depends only on X:

```css
.btn-matrix > .btn {
  width: (100/X)%;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(Xn+X+1) {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(n+X+1) {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.btn-matrix > .btn:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(X) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-last-child(X) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

### Three column button matrix with Bootstrap 4 or 5

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/ZEKKoJG

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";

/* Arrange buttons */
.btn-matrix {
   flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow buttons to jump to another row */
}
.btn-matrix > .btn {
   width: 33%; /* force buttons to have the same width regardless of content */
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(3n + 4) {
   margin-left: 0; /* because .btn-group adds `margin-left: -1px;` to all buttons */
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(n + 4) {
   margin-top: -1px; /* superimpose borders of the buttons from adjacent rows */
}

/* Fix border radius */
.btn-matrix > .btn:first-child {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(3) {
   border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-last-child(3) {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:last-child {
   border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

/* Decorations */
.btn-matrix {
   margin: 20px;
   max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-matrix" role="group" aria-label="Three Column Button Matrix">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 5</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 6</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 7</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 8</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 9</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 10</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 11</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 12</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 13</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 14</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 15</button>
</div>
```

##### X×Y matrix with Bootstrap 4 or 5

The code depends only on X:

```css
.btn-matrix {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn {
  width: (100/X)%;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(Xn+X+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(n+X+1) {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.btn-matrix > .btn:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(X) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-last-child(X) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is exactly I have asked about

Comment: This mostly still works in bootstrap 4, but you need to add .btn-matrix { flex-wrap: wrap; } or the buttons will not wrap around.

Answer (score 1):

Modified @Pranjal answer a bit because of following reason:

- the bootstrap grid (row, col-... etc) creates rows which are by definition 12 columns wide

Because of this we create a div with class row for each row of 3 buttons. Also, we want the buttons the be 1/3 of the width of the row (12 columns) so we give it the class "col-md-4" (12 divided by 3).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">            
  <div class="row">          
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 4</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 5</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 6</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 7</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 8</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-4">Button 9</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I make left and right sides of matrix more straight? (like .btn-group-vertical class makes it)

Comment: Then you would have to make one row, which contains 3 columns (col-md-4 each). In each column you would place a vertical button group. However this will give the middle group the same layout so you have to play around a bit to find the desired result.

Comment: I would like to have straight lines at the top and bottom of the matrix, so it doesn't solve the problem. I think about merging .btn-group and .btn-group-vertical in some way, maybe, by edite css files or overwrite them. But I'm not good at css.

Comment: Yes custom CSS will be needed then. Give it a try and make a new question when you are stuck :) This question can be closed I assume.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 6</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 7</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 8</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 9</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks. what about straight lines of the sides of matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will be helpful to you.Try this one.

```css
button{
  margin-right:14px!important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">            
  <div class="row">          
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 4</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 5</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 6</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 7</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 8</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 9</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the thing  you want?

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 and if you have unequal text that needs to wrap.

```
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(3n+4) {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(n+4) {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-child(3) {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:nth-last-child(3) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}
.btn-matrix > .btn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

/* Decorations */
.btn-matrix { flex-wrap: wrap; }
/* force wrap text */
 .btn-matrix .btn{
white-space: normal !important;
}


<div class="btn-group btn-matrix">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 1 Extra Content</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 2</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 3</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 4</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 5</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 6</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 7</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 8</a>
  <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-sm-4">Button 9</a>
</div>
```