# Align 4 groups of 4 bootstrap btn's in 1 row and 4 rows in small media

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to line up 2 rows of in larger media and have them collapse into a lined up grid in smaller media. btn-group-justified works for the representation on small media, but creates 4 rows on larger media. I tried .btn-matrix [How I can make nice looking matrix of buttons with bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261294/how-i-can-make-nice-looking-matrix-of-buttons-with-bootstrap-3) , but it generates 4 rows as well. Here is the html:

```js
window.onresize = resize;
function resize() {
  var curwidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  //console.log("resize event detected:"+curwidth);
  if(curwidth<992){
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-group btn-group-qtr col-md-3');
    i = els.length;
    while (i--) {
      els[i].className = 'btn-group btn-group-justified col-md-3';
    }
  }else{
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-group btn-group-justified col-md-3');
    i = els.length;
    while (i--) {
      els[i].className = 'btn-group btn-group-qtr col-md-3';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.btn-group-qtr {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.btn-group-qtr > .btn,
.btn-group-qtr > .btn-group {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  width: 1%;
}
.btn-group-qtr > .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>btn groups</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    .btn-group-qtr {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.btn-group-qtr > .btn,
.btn-group-qtr > .btn-group {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  width: 1%;
}
.btn-group-qtr > .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form role="form" name="myForm1" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class= "form-group">
          <div class="row btn-group">
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-qtr col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sched</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">New</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lookup</a>
            </span>
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-qtr col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Change</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Notes</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Info</a>
            </span>
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-qtr col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Chgs</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pmts</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Stmt</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Hist</a>
            </span>
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-qtr col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pol</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Img</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">DmdIns</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">PmtIns</a>
            </span>
              </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Account</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Command</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Ticket</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">AcctList</span>
                <select class="form-control" style="min-width:100%;">
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>13072</option>
                  <option>50000</option>
                  <option>59949</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form role="form" name="myForm2" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class= "form-group">
          <div class="row btn-group">
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-justified col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sched</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">New</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lookup</a>
            </span>
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-justified col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Change</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Notes</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Info</a>
            </span>
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-justified col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Chgs</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pmts</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Stmt</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Hist</a>
            </span>
            <span class="btn-group btn-group-justified col-md-3">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pol</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Img</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">DmdIns</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">PmtIns</a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Account</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Command</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Ticket</span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">AcctList</span>
                <select class="form-control" style="min-width:100%;">
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>13072</option>
                  <option>50000</option>
                  <option>59949</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Form1 section looks fine on large media, but collapses into a jumble of buttons that have varying widths on small media. Any ideas how to make them line up after collapsing and look similar to Form2? -- TIA

UPDATE: added a quick-fix in javascript to switch classes on window resize at hard-coded breakpoint. Still need to compute the differences between the 2 classes and create @media queries to resolve them vs. using this quick-fix.

Comment: Flexbox layout on modern browsers, adjusted according to CSS `@media` queries, would be something to look into.

Comment: Or possibly set up a switch from btn-group-qtr to btn-group-justified at a certain pixel threshold? - Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can change classes in JavaScript, but you don't want to use JavaScript where CSS will do. Rather than changing the class with JS, keep the class the same but change the rule that applies depending on the width. You can do that using blocks like `@media (max-width: 50em) { ... }` (or min-width) around the rules that apply at a certain device width.

Comment: I'm sure that will be the best method to use for re-usability. It will just take a bit longer to code... For the meantime, I've added a quick-fix in javascript that seems to work.