# Create a button-group table with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, buttongroup

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I'm having problems trying to create a button group with multiple rows, like sketched in the image below. The usual button groups in Bootstrap only seem to support buttons aranged in one row or column.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this taking advantage of the already existing button support from Bootstrap, without having to write CSS/JavaScript from scratch?

---

Related, but this only answers the question in case the buttons are nicely aligned in a matrix: [How I can make nice looking matrix of buttons with bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261294/how-i-can-make-nice-looking-matrix-of-buttons-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align them by using `row` and `col` classes.

Example With minumum css:

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="inline">
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col">btn1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-6">btn2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-6">btn3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4">btn4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4">btn5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4">btn6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

A Copy Of Image Example:

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="inline">
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col">btn1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-6">btn2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-6">btn3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4">btn4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4">btn5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4">btn6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I've added important to styles to override bootstrap styles. If you import your stylesheet after bootstrap css you don't have to add `!important` to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Two remarks: in the first example all corners of every button are rounded, which gives a weird appearance. The second example looks great except for two things: firstly, because the border radius is only set for the container, the buttons themselves stick out at the corners (which becomes more clear when you raise the border-radius). Secondly, giving a border to the container creates an ugly one-pixel white line right between the border and the buttons (at least in my browser, chrome). Any way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm using chrome, but i cant find the 1px white border between container and buttons, And for the first note i didn't quite understand it, can you explain it more ?

Comment: I am seeing this in my browser (Chrome version 75.0.3770.142): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRiGV.jpg . I guess this is a bug in Chrome. To exaggerate my first point, this is what I see when I raise the border radius to 20px: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEvOO.jpg . For example, the upper corners of btn1 stick out of the containing div. When the border radius is only 5px this is more subtle but still visible.

Comment: @Mark_Ed I think I figured it out: I'm on Windows and one of the default settings scales everything with 125%. Once I turn this off, the white pixel I show in the first image of my previous comment disappears. Still think it's some bug caused by chrome, but that's another issue than the one I wanted to adress here. As for my other comment: I fixed it by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `.outline` class. Thanks for the help!